# Python - BS4 - how to grab text not wrapped in an html tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<p>
Beth Weatherby, Ph.D.
<br/>
Chancellor<br/>
<a href="mailto:beth.weatherby@umwestern.edu">beth.weatherby@umwestern.edu</a>, (406) 683-7151</p>strong text
```

I need to grab Beth Weatherby out of this HTML and then grab Chancellor and save both to different variables - without using any other libraries but BS4. I was trying next_sibling and things like that but I totally need help.

Comment: Is this the full HTML? Are there any tags before this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you only know the exact text, try to search for the text using the `text=“My text”` argument, and than use `find_next()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<p>
Beth Weatherby, Ph.D.
<br/>
Chancellor<br/>
<a href="mailto:beth.weatherby@umwestern.edu">beth.weatherby@umwestern.edu</a>, (406) 683-7151</p>strong text
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


for tag in soup.find_all(text=lambda t: 'Beth Weatherby, Ph.D.' in t):
    print(tag.strip())
    print(tag.find_next(text=True).strip())
```

Output:

```
Beth Weatherby, Ph.D.
Chancellor
```

Comment: Thanks for the assist but that will not work - I need to be able to grab any text as I have a list of rows that look like this that I am iterating through. The name changes in each row.

Comment: @Escape2Hogwarts Please edit the full HTML to your question